# PHP Contact form redirects

Tags: php, forms, action, contact-form

So I have a from that basically when it submits it runs through what i have on "contact-process.php" and when clicking on submit it will go to that page and then show the success or error, how do I make the submit show the success or error message on the same page and clear the form to show it's sent. here's the code I have on my web page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="contact-process.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject2" name="subject2" placeholder="Logo Design - Request">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Please explain your request in detail. Provide screenshots & links."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">5 x 2 = ?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10  col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input type="submit"  class="btn-primary btn" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And then this is the code I have on "contact-process.php"

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject2 = $_POST["subject2"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$human = intval($_POST['human']);

$EmailTo = "example@outlook.com";
$Subject = "Message Received";

if ($human !== 10) {
    $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
}

// prepare email body text
 $Body = "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n\n\n";

$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $subject2;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank You! I will be in touch</div>";
}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Put the php code and the form in the same page.

Comment: if it's on the same page, what will the action be, do I need to ID it? and no erros, just the success shows on a different page.

Comment: action will be action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" OR action="#" OR action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"

Comment: It's constantly showing this: http://prntscr.com/afnzhx

Comment: This means that the php mail function returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the html to your PHP script as following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject2" name="subject2" placeholder="Logo Design - Request">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Please explain your request in detail. Provide screenshots & links."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">5 x 2 = ?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10  col-sm-offset-2">
                            <input type="submit"  class="btn-primary btn" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if($_POST["name"] != "" AND $_POST["email"] != "" AND $_POST["subject2"] != "" AND $_POST["message"] != "") {

         $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $subject2 = $_POST["subject2"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);

        $EmailTo = "example@outlook.com";
        $Subject = "Message Received";

        if ($human !== 10) {

            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Your anti-spam is incorrect</div>";

        }else{

           // prepare email body text
            $Body = "Name: ";
            $Body .= $name;
            $Body .= "\n";

            $Body .= "Email: ";
            $Body .= $email;
            $Body .= "\n\n\n";

            $Body .= "Subject: ";
            $Body .= $subject2;
            $Body .= "\n";

            $Body .= "Message: ";
            $Body .= $message;
            $Body .= "\n";

            // send email
            $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

            // redirect to success page
            if ($success){

               echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank You! I will be in touch</div>";

            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>";

            }
        }


    }else{

        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Data incomplate</div>";
    }

}else{
    // do nothing
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

action will be:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

OR

```
action="#"
```

OR

```
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
```

Comment: I've tried this however it's constantly showing "Thank You! I will be in touch" should it be elseif instead of jsut else?

Comment: It' not good, it's constantly showing it, always there, never disapearing, thats there when the page loads. it's not waiting till submission

Comment: close your internet browser and start it again. The php code will be only executed when the form has been submitted.

Comment: Ahhh ahha! Cheers :D <3

Comment: Holod up, tried a test one, it submitted, sent the email, however it contained NO Content that i inputted into the form?..

Comment: You have to check, if all information are entered. I have edited my answer. Use the new code

Answer (score 0):

Seek ye first ... then asks

You need to know a little [Ajax](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) is a technology that allows you to communicate with php javascript / JSON

Example:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Make a script with alert function then inside the script put location.reload in the success part.